# C# Beginner, trying to change a fixed background color of a form with text in a textbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, background-color

I am a total beginner with c#, i am learning with Udemy.

I have done just a little start but now i want to test for my own.

i have learned how to use a button to change the background color of a form.

```
BackColor = Color.Red; etc.
```

I am now trying to make a textbox where i can write in for example Red, Blue, Green ect and the click a button, then the form will change to that color.
I want to have fixed colors i can choose from so i am guessing i need to make fixed colors in the formload "tab"?

```
private void FrmColorCalculator_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 
            
            Color red = Color.Red;
            Color green = Color.Green;
```

should this be in formload? how to make fixed colors? i get an errormessages saying "cannot convert system.drawing.color to string, but thats not what i want to do, i want the color to change.

If someone would be willing to kick me in the right direction?

Comment: are you working with Xamarin forms?

Comment: "how to make fixed colors?" You could make an Array of choices, then see if what the user typed in is in the Array. A better choice would be to use a ComboBox or a ListBox instead of a TextBox, though.

Comment: How would you go forward making a Array with for example 4 colors?

Comment: Hi, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 2):

"I am now trying to make a textbox where i can write in for example Red, Blue, Green ect and the click a button, then the form will change to that color."

Use [Color.FromName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromname?view=net-6.0) like this:

```
private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        this.BackColor = Color.FromName(textBox1.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid color: " + textBox1.Text);
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Idle_Mind’s answer can help you change the background color to the color you type in textbox.

If you want to choose fixed colors you can use combobox instead of textbox.

Here is the code:

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Red");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Blue");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Green");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Yellow");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
            this.BackColor = Color.FromName(comboBox1.Text);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change form color you can do this by editing the property BackColor,

```
Form form1= new Form();

private void FrmColorCalculator_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

     form1.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

f you mean a WPF Window you can use the Background property.
From within the Window's code:

```
Background = Brushes.LightPink;
```

Comment: I am only learning winforms now, going for WPF later.

Answer (score 0):

simple change the color of the text inside the textbox using following code.

```
txtYourTextBox.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```